# NLP- context classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

Being new to NLP and Machine learning, i'm struck at giving solution approach for a specific problem. we are building a bot which answers generic question about financial FAQs.

Problem is,how do i tag/group questions, for e.x:

- tell me about Mutual fund ?
- What is Mutual  fund ?
- Explain me about Mutual  fund ?

falls under same context of **"What"**.

Similarly for "Why","When" and "How much".

I thought of using

```
text=nltk.word_tokenize("What is current price of APPL")
print nltk.pos_tag(text)
grammar = r"""
NP:
{<.*>+}          # Chunk everything
}<WP|WRB>+{      # Chink sequences of WP and IN
 """
cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
result = cp.parse(nltk.pos_tag(text))
```

and count the (what/how/why)tags if any, to categorize it. But it seems very stupid way.

Is there any better way to achieve it?

Comment: If the "stupid way" gives you satisfactory performance (measure it!), then go ahead and use it. If not, I'd train a classifier with whatever features you think are relevant.

Comment: @alexis: if you're forced to use a classifier for this scenario, which one you'd suggest?. Sorry, novice in ML here :)

Comment: I would suggest you try several and see which one performs best. Start simple (`NaiveBayes`), then plug in some others; the nltk's classifiers have a pretty consistent API.